# Present storyboard view controller from third party library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, cocoapods

I have installed a third party library using cocoapods and am trying to present the storyboard contained within the library in my projects viewDidLoad.  My code below i believe should be working

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"library.storyboard" bundle:nil];
WrapperViewController *myVC = (WrapperViewController*) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"libraryStoryboard"];
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I am receiving this error when i run    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'library.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle.

Any ideas why this will not build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The name parameter is the name of your **.storyboard** file (without the extension).
2. first check that storyboard is located in your main bundle. if not than change the bundle name from

> **From**
>
> ```
> UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"library.storyboard" bundle:nil];
> ```
>
> **To**
>
> ```
> UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"library" bundle:[NSBundle <name of bundle or mainbundle>]];
> ```

3. The simulator is not case sensitive, but the device is. so please check name is correct

Comment: @ work_gg please share what was the solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

If the actual file is named `library.storyboard` in the bundle, then in your `storyboardWithName` method you would only write `library`. Its also case sensitive so make sure you've got the name right. So it should be `storyboardWithName:@"library"`

And is that storyboard in your main bundle?

Comment: @"library" is part of the thridparty library that i have imported using cocoa pods.